# login functionality working in my mvc 5 application but after some action its automatically Logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

login functionality working in my mvc 5 application but after some action its automatically Logout
and redirect to login page.
i have used form authentication method to Active login session

I don't know why its logout automatically after some time

Comment: There can be plenty of reasons. Can you a pattern in what you are doing when you are logged out? Maybe after the application pool is restarted, or if you have been idle for a while? Or maybe you are switching hostnames, which means your previous authentication cookie is not send again. A bit more information about how you configured the authentication would be useful if you want help.

Comment: @VincentBitter I am just Posting form and its redirect to login page or some time site keep loading for 2-3 minute after submit the form in this case I refresh the page an its redirect to login page